# Accessing instance methods using subclass and superclass references

Tags: java, inheritance

Here is the sample code:

```
package com.ankur.javapractice;
public class SuperClass {

    public void someMethod(int val) {
        System.out.println("Public method in SuperClass");
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Public method in SubClass");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SuperClass superClassRef = new SubClass();
        SubClass subClassRef = new SubClass();
        //superClassRef.someMethod(); // (1)
        subClassRef.someMethod(8); // (2)
    }
}
```

I understand why (1) won't work **at compile time** (that's why I have it commented out). It won't work because `someMethod()` is not known to `superClassRef` since it is of type `SuperClass` and `SuperClass` does not define `someMethod()`.

My question is why/how does (2) work then at compile time? Using the same explanation as above, **at compile time**, `someMethod(int)` is also not known to `subClassRef` since it is of type `SubClass` and `SubClass` does not define `someMethod(int)`.

Edit and Update:

Some answers pointed out that `SubClass` inherits `someMethod(int)` from `SuperClass`. That is correct and I understand that; my follow up question to that is how is compiler able to take inheritence relationships into account ?

Comment: SubClass is of type SuperClass and SuperClass defines someMethod(int)

Comment: @DanielMesejo But does that mean that the compiler takes inheritence into account ? How is compiler able to take inheritence into account ?

Comment: Yes the compiler takes inheritance into account, because is a compiler for the Java language and the Java language defines inheritance. Now how does the compiler resolves inheritance it is a broad question, you can think that the compiler tracks each definition of each class a given class intherits and add those defitions to the sub class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because SubClass inherits someMethod(int) and has someMethod(), so it has two different methods.
SuperClass cannot access someMethod() because it is not extending any classes.

Comment: Update the question, with an edit. How does compiler take inheritence into account ?

Comment: The compiler converts Java code to Bytecode and at this point does some checks and optimizations, I believe it is at this point that it checks the relationship of classes by analyzing composition, inheritance, among other issues.

Comment: Look a this links with more information about Java JIT Compiler

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/Oracle-JVM-JIT.html#GUID-23D5BA60-A2B3-45F9-93DF-81A3D971CA50

https://aboullaite.me/understanding-jit-compiler-just-in-time-compiler/

Comment: Juliano, Just to be clear, the links you posted are for JIT compiler (which comes into play at runtime) whereas the `inheritence` considerations are taken into account by `javac` (not JIT).

Comment: @AnkurAgarwal are you right. In fact I know more about JIT that Javac process, because due to day to day learning more concepts about JIT than Javac. I don't know very much about compilers, but I do know that there is usually a phase called Syntactic (or Syntax) analysis, where the compiler do some verifications about grammar language, reserved words and other rules. I guess Javac do the inheritence verification in this phase before generate the .class file.

Comment: I found this link about Open JDK compilation where is showed a **Parser and Enter** stage, and this is probably where inheritance validation between classes occurs. http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/compilation-overview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes `someMethod(int)` is defined in parent class which is `SuperClass`, but when  child class inherits parents class using `extends` keyword then subclass inherits all of the public and protected members of its parent and can use them directly, which is called [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

> A subclass inherits all of the public and protected members of its parent, no matter what package the subclass is in. If the subclass is in the same package as its parent, it also inherits the package-private members of the parent. You can use the inherited members as is, replace them, hide them, or supplement them with new members:

- **The inherited methods can be used directly as they are.**

Comment: But does that mean that the compiler takes `inheritence` into account ? How is compiler able to take inheritence into account ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your doubt `how is compiler able to take inheritence relationships into account ?` but Compiler generates the bytecode of all classes during compilation by validation all rules (OOPS, syntax) @AnkurAgarwal